# CSS tag rendering

Tags: html, css

For navigation menu I am using `ul` `li`. Will there be any change in performance if I use `ol` `li`?

Comment: Methinks you have a fundamental misunderstanding somewhere. You shouldn't be trying to optimize your **HTML** for performance.

Comment: In this case no, but if you had a lot of data or a lot of traffic, you could try to "optimize" HTML to make it smaller or load faster (not talking about ol vs ul here).

Answer (score 1):

I think the only difference is that ul is ***unordered list*** and ol is ***ordered list***. I don't think there will be any performance concern in this. Even if there is any it won't be noticeable.

ol is used wherever there is a defined order of things that are displayed.

ul is used when the order of things doesn't matter.

See this SO post also for more details

[when to use UL or OL in html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1039827/when-to-use-ul-or-ol-in-html)

Answer (score 0):

Nope, there shouldn't be any. At least nothing a user or developer would ever notice.

Usually navigation menu consists of links in no particular order (other then the one in which you put em), that's why people use unordered list (ul). It's just a logical decision, you could easily simulate ul while using ol and vice versa using css and maybe a little bit more text.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with the other guys. You will not get lower (or higher) performance if you use ol instead of ul.

Answer (score 0):

The only difference is that `<ol>` has numbered points instead of bullets, but performance-wise there is no difference.

Adding some CSS can make both look the same:

```
ol {
list-style:none;
}

or

ul {
list-style:none;
}
```