# How to keep elements under a li element in the same line?

Tags: html, css

I want my elements under a li to display in the single line. If the characters exceeds the length of the div then it should wrap.

Here is the link of my fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/NmhB5/

Now I want that in that div my all element inside a li element should be in the same like. For Example:

```
O 1.abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
O 2. 12345678901234567890
```

and like that. 
Now as we can see that it is exceeding the length of the div so I want to wrap it like this.

```
O 1. abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv
     wxyz
O 2. 12345678901234567890
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using the below CSS:

```
span {
    display: block;
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

Also, given that you are effectively numbering the list again, why not use the ordered list (`<ol>`) tags instead of using an unordered list (`<ul>`) and then adding an extra span for the numbering.

I would recommend the below markup:

```
<div>
    <ol>
        <li>abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</li>
        <li>123456789012345678901234567890</li>
    </ol>
    <ol>
        <li>abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</li>
        <li>123456789012345678901234567890</li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div {
   right: 0px;
   width: 200px;
   border: double;
   position: absolute;
}

li {
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/NmhB5/4/)

**Note:** You may want to refer to this thread on [when to use UL or OL in html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1039827/when-to-use-ul-or-ol-in-html). But the crux of both this answer and the one posted by [Paulie_D](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2802040/paulie-d) are the same in the sense that both use the `word-break` property.

**Update:** For wrapping around whole word to the next line when it overflows, you can use the below setting.

```
li {
    word-wrap: break-word;
    /* Webkit supports word-break: break-word; also but it seems to be non-standard */
}
```

[**Updated Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/NmhB5/7/)

Comment: word-break: break-all will break a word from anywhere but what I want that if I have to break the word then the entire word should go to the next line. How to do that?

Comment: @user3745870: Please refer my update in the answer mate.

Comment: if this I wrote it like this http://jsfiddle.net/7Luh4/ then how can I make sure that the text which says "I am a software engineer. I am still trying to be a good one" does not come  below the img?

Comment: Very rough attempt but you can try something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/7Luh4/1/).

Comment: That seems good but lets say I display a border when I hover over the text and I want that the border should be as long as the text is. In this case, if I will just write border:double then it will be same for all texts as the width is same. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Did not get you. Can you show a sample(maybe an image)?

Comment: See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7Luh4/5/ Hover the text and you will see dashed border. Hover "I", it's border is longer than it. I want that border should also be same as the text.

Comment: StackOverflow doesn't encourage extending the same thread multiple times mate, but I will answer it this time alone. You can set `width` to auto (meaning set as much as required to fit the content) and set `max-width` to a percentage (so that width doesn't exceed it causing the div to be pushed down) like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7Luh4/7/).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will keep in mind about not to extend a thread multiple times. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 3):

You could add this

```
span {
   display: inline-block;
   word-break:break-all; /* add this */
}
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/NmhB5/1/)

Comment: +1 mate. Sorry, didn't notice your answer before I added mine.

Comment: No worries...yours is still valuable as it offers more stylistic options I omited as I wasn't sure exactly what the OP wanted.

Comment: word-break: break-all will break a word from anywhere but what I want that if I have to break the word then the entire word should go to the next line. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

you know you can have a ordered list with numbers, for example http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_ol_list-style-type&preval=decimal-leading-zero

**for example**

html

```
<ol>
    <li> jguhiuo</li>
    <li> jhii</li>
</ol>
```

css

```
 ol#myList
{
list-style-type:decimal;
}
```

link
http://jsfiddle.net/NmhB5/5/