# What's the point of unordered list <ul></ul> in html?

Tags: html, html-lists

Newbie question, for a list, both `<ul>...<ul>` and `<ol>...<ol>` seem to give the same thing. I was expecting the unordered list to be randomly ordered once rendered by browser but that is not the case, so then what is the point of unordered list?

```html
<ul style="list-style-type:circle">
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>

<ol style="list-style-type:circle">
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: use it without "list-style-type", then you see the difference.

Comment: try google, you could find alot of answers before even asking on stack

Comment: Does this answer your question? [when to use UL or OL in html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1039827/when-to-use-ul-or-ol-in-html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<ul>` tag is used for an unordered list and the elements within it are displayed with bullet points by default.

The `<ol>` tag is used for ordered lists and the elements within it are numbered in order.

You can see the difference if you remove the list-style-type attribute.

`<ul>` would produce:

• Element 1

• Element 2

But for `<ol>`, this would be:

1. Element 1
2. Element 2

Comment: plus: one is bullet points (symbol without a number), the other is numbered points -because @夜粪侠 set the "circle" style on `<ol>` this overrides the default numbering with a circle because it is a more ***specific*** property than `<ol>` - @sproutmaster can you add this to explain why your code displays different to the OP's.